# LatLngToLayerPoint transformation to pixel coordinates

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, react-leaflet

I am writing a test for leaf-let Map component using jest and React-testing-library.

My **Map** component uses some map method for example LatLngToLayerPoint.

Where as to I also mock 'react-leaflet' library that does not include the LatLngToLayerPoint method. I think I have to write a custom method for this transformation as a mock function.  Can anyone help? or identify a possible solution?

For mocking leafleat I use this link 
[https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/**mocks**/leaflet.js](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/__mocks__/leaflet.js)

Answer (score 0):

The React-Leaflet library creates an instance of a leaflet map which does indeed contain all the same tools as any other leaflet map.  For something like this you're best off accessing this method from within the `componentDidMount` method, using a reference to the map.

```js
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

class Map extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){

    // leafletElement is the leaflet object created by any react-leaflet component
    const map = this.mapReference.leafletElement 
    const layerPoint = map.latLngToLayerPoint(map.getCenter())

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <LeafletMap
        ref={mapReference => this.mapReference = mapReference}
        zoom={4}
        center={[33.852169, -100.5322]} >

        <TileLayer ... />

      </LeafletMap>
    );

  }

}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/latlngtolayerpoint-lives-4pqqp) is a working codesandbox.